# Need help to disable back-forward cache on Safari iOS

Tags: ios, caching, safari, mobile-safari

I need help to disable back-forward cache on Safari iOS. I tried suggestions provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788802/prevent-safari-loading-from-cache-when-back-button-is-clickEd) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137588/how-do-you-disable-back-and-forward-caching-on-ios-safari) but it didn't help.

The functionality that I am trying to achieve is on a multi-page form when a user clicks on the back button he should not be allowed to edit the information on the previous form page. For this I have a modal popup blocking the edit when user clicks back and it works fine on desktop browser and on android but doesn't work as expected on iPhone because of back-forward cache on Safari iOS.

Comment: I also tried putting in the below iFrame as per the suggestion [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20070612072521/http://developer.apple.com/internet/safari/faq.html#anchor5) but it didn't help - 

<iframe style="height:0px;width:0px;visibility:hidden" src="about:blank">
    this frame prevents back forward cache
</iframe>

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue and none of the solutions posted are helping. Thanks!

Comment: No, I didn't get a solution for this. I had to implement a workaround that triggers a post back from the server side. 

This approach has a drawback that at first the user would the page from the cache when he clicks back on Safari browser, but once he takes any action on the page my workaround logic would determine that there was actually a back button clicked and refresh the page and show the modal popup as required blocking the page edit.